# How is music encoded in a vinyl?

Tags: waves, acoustics, information

I'm asking about something that looks like magic to me. I know that waves can be combined into one by "summing" them, but I guess there are different combinations of waves that lead to the same resulting wave. I also know that the movement of the needle througout the vinyl  is what holds the information that aftwerwads makes the sound.

But how can all those sounds be enconded in a 2-dimensional movement (maybe 3-dimensional if the needle goes up and down?) without any loss of necessary information? I've heard that is has to do with Fourier Analysis, which I'm not an expert of, but it's okay if you relate to that in you answers.

Also, do our brains intervene in this recreation of the sound in a way that is not necessary to encode all the information, but just enough to let our brains to the rest (for example something similar occurs with harmonic sounds)?

Comment: Gramophone recording is an interesting topic and involves integration of the signal before recording, because the cartridge is sensitive to the speed (derivative) rather than the displacement. However, this is not physics, so I vote to close.

Comment: @safesphere I thought it was physics, where should I ask about it then?

Comment: @safesphere How is this not physics? Isn't the vynil read through mechanical medium (the needle)? I would like you to expand on the notion that the process is speed sensitive, since the rotational speed of the vynil is constant. Do you mean that the groove varies its angular trajectory along the circular path in order to vary the speed at which the needle moves through? Meaning than if the groove was just a plain circle, the needle wouldn't move at all, and if the groove was a regular sinus-like shape, the speed would also be constant even though it induces movement perpendicular to the circul

Comment: Why should the two dimensional movement not be enough. The information your ear gives you is that about the one-dimensional movement of the eardrum, that is some function $f(t)$. Exactly that is encoded on a vinyl record: some elongation with respect to time (where the time is mapped to distance along the groove and the elongation to depth/side way wiggling of the groove). Stereo works by encoding two such signals one on the left, the other on the right slope of the groove.

Comment: @SebastianRiese I think I didn't explain my doubt properly, it's not about the dimensions, but rather that music usually have lots of sounds combined, and I'm not sure if then the individual sounds are inseparable since they are mixed in a unique sound wave and what we hear is just this resulting wave, that feels like every one of them being played together.

Comment: Yes, but then what is the difference between that scenario and the sound wave in the air. In the air there is also only one quantity that describes the sound at your ear: the pressure of the air. You eardrum is vibrating and a single signal (the elongation) is derived from that. Of course the vinyl record cannot restore the full spatial information of the wave (that is, if you move before the speakers the sound will be slightly different than if you moved around before the original source of sound).

Comment: Okay I think I get it know, I had some misconceptions. Thank you

Comment: @MaximeBoivin I mean the stylus speed across the groove (due to the modulation), not the rotation speed of the platter. This topic is engineering, not physics.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing together at least three different questions: (1) How do different, simultaneous sounds add together? (2) How does sound recording work? (with particular attention to vinyl disks) (3) How does our sense of hearing work? Probably some of those (especially No. 3) could be further broken down into even more questions.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: No information is lost because you only need 1 dimension of motion to reproduce a sound wave.

The field of audio engineering and recording is decades old, and there is a mountain of research on how best to record and play back sound. The process I describe here is most likely not reflective of the state of the art, and necessarily skips over many details; this answer is meant to illuminate the conceptual underpinnings of the recording process at its simplest level.

The motion of a needle in a record player is indeed 2-dimensional. We can decompose this motion into 2 components: the (pretty much constant) forward motion of the needle around the record, and the (highly variable) side-to-side motion of the needle as it's deflected by the sides of the groove that it's in. As long as your record player is good enough that the forward motion is basically constant, we can basically ignore the forward motion and treat the needle as an object that moves in only 1 dimension, side to side within its groove.*

The needle is connected to a *diaphragm*, which is basically just a thin, flexible membrane. When the needle moves side-to-side, it moves the diaphragm in and out (in other words, the 1-D motion of the needle is coupled to the 1-D motion of the diaphragm). When the diaphragm moves in and out, it pushes and pulls on the air, which creates pressure waves; these pressure waves are, in fact, what sound waves are. These sound waves travel through the air and into someone's ear, which has another diaphragm in it (your eardrum). The pressure waves move this diaphragm in and out, which deforms some hairs that are touching it. The particular way in which the hairs are deformed generates an electrical signal, which travels to your brain; your brain takes this electrical signal and interprets it into the perception of sound. So basically, the playback of a record is just one diaphragm vibrating another diaphragm, which are linked by a column of air.

Recording works basically the same way as playback, but in reverse. Sounds (pressure waves in the air) push a diaphragm in and out. This diaphragm is connected to a needle, in such a way that the in-and-out motion of the diaphragm causes a side-to-side motion of the needle. The needle is traveling through the groove of a blank, soft record (usually made of lacquer). Before the needle passes, the grooves have straight walls. As the needle passes, the side-to-side motion of the needle deforms the soft walls of the groove, which remain deformed, preserving a record of the needle's side-to-side motion. For playback, this soft record is then turned into the normal vinyl one, so instead of creating new deformations, the needle will be deflected by the ones that are there.

The fact that the recording and playback processes are (in the limit of a perfect process) exactly the reverse of each other means that in the ideal case, the deformations in the walls of the groove in the record cause the diaphragm to vibrate in exactly the same way that it did when recording. As such, no information is lost, in the ideal case. In reality, neither the recording nor the playback process is perfect, so very low-frequency sounds (which only very gently move the needle) and very high-frequency sounds (which move the needle faster than the soft walls can react) are not likely to be accurately recorded or played back. This manifests itself as an absence of bass and a high-pitched hiss when playing back most vinyl records. In addition, dust contamination and manufacturing defects will cause pops and crackles in the playback, and warping of the record or inconsistency in rotation will cause a slow "wobble" in the sound. But on paper, this process does not have any inherent information loss.

*The needle's side-to-side motion and its forward motion are actually coupled; the faster the needle moves forward, the more rapidly it will encounter deformations in the sides of the groove. As such, variations in forward motion will cause variations in the overall pitch of the sound, which we usually call "wobble".

Comment: OMG! How old are you man? You are describing a hundred year old process for shellac discs, not vinyl. One clever point there is the fact that the needle moves sideways, as you correctly stated. This way dust in the groove that creates a vertical needle motion does not create noise. The vinyl technology is mostly stereo with 2D movement of the stylus in the groove, 45 degrees each channel. The recorded signal (aside from the standard equalization) is an integral of the musical signal, because modern cartridges are sensitive to the speed and thus reproduce the derivative of the recorded signal.